# How can I display the graph generated in QWidget in a Dialog? Both screens are pre-built and have other widgets as well

Tags: python, qt-designer, qgraphicsview

[image]

[image]

I am building a project that, according to the first image, takes the inputs from the user, and according to the second image, prints a series of information in a dialog page, and I want to draw a graph as well. Please guide me how to draw the graph in QGraphicsView on the second page

I used the following function for this:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def show_lists_as_plot(output, listx, listy):
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(listx, listy)
        canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
        output.graphics_view.setScene(QGraphicsScene())
        output.graphics_view.scene().addWidget(canvas)
```

that the output corresponds to the Dialog call:

```
        output = out.Ui_Dialog2()
        dialog2 = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        output.setupUi(dialog2)
```